# What is the name of the introvert-extravert concentration scale diagram?

Tags: personality, concentration, introversion

I heard [Dr Brian Little](http://www.brianrlittle.com/) stand up and give a great talk on personality types.

On one of his slides - he showed a 'concentration scale diagram' with introverts at the top, ambiverts in the middle, and extraverts at the bottom. He made the point that optimal concentration is in the middle of the diagram - where the ambiverts are.

(You can see it in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ5o9PcHeL0&t=8m23s) from a different presentation at 8:23)

His subsequent point was that the caffeine in coffee had an 'upward pushing effect' - which would lift an extravert into an optimal zone of concentration, but would have a negative effect on an introvert. (They would be lifted away from the optimal zone of concentration.

My question is: **What is the name of the introvert-extravert concentration scale diagram?**